# Finding strings within a string

Tags: string, scheme

I have to find substring from a string and I was wondering what's the simplest way to go about it. Not looking for a coding solution here but ideas i.e. what algorithm do I use given I am trying to work this using programming language called Scheme.

So let's say I have the following input:

Pattern = This ... fox is a good ... house of legion ... town
String = This quick brown fox is a good fox in the house of house of legion in our great town

Output should be (list of lists):

((quick brown) (fox in the house of) (in our great) )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard string matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093426/wildcard-string-matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing would be best served with regular expressions. Racket example:

```
(regexp-match #rx"This (.*) fox is a good (.*) house of legion (.*) town"
              "This quick brown fox is a good fox in the house of house of legion in our great town")
=> ("This quick brown fox is a good fox in the house of house of legion in our great town"
    "quick brown"
    "fox in the house of"
    "in our great")
```

The `regexp-match` procedure returns a list of capture groups (capture group 0 is the entire input string), or `#f` if the match failed.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. If I have to implement (.*) functionality on my own, how do I go about it? Any pointers or links are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much do you want to do yourself? SRFI-13 has `string-contains`, which returns the index of a substring. If you are unwilling to use that, too, you can always build your own string-index procedure. That should be easier than implementing regular expressions.