# String Matching with dot

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I need to design a data structure to which I can efficiently add new words(Strings) and search for an existing word. Also, the search word can contain "." in it which can match any character. For eg. if I add strings "abcd" and "abed" then search for "ab.d" should return me both of them.

I tried to tackle this using prefix Tries. It works fine for normal string search(without dot) but for dot I have to search for every child of a node. Is there a more efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: When you meet a `.`, apply DFS on that Trie node.

Comment: cross site question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95665/64229

Comment: @hiimdaosui That appears to be what OP already had in mind. In general it should work, but it may be infeasible if you have too many wildcards or too high branching factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Wildcard string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093426/wildcard-string-matching). See also: [Wildcard pattern matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-pattern-matching/).

Comment: A [generalized suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) could work, although update is expensive. You could, however, have a secondary structure that contains the words to be added, and build the new GST on a background thread. So a query would search the existing GST, and also use a less efficient method to search the pending words.

Comment: Using a TST (Ternary Search Trie) is more efficient in this case. A TST has only 3 children at the most. It can be deep but usually efficient.

Comment: I think it is not a problem that you need to search for every child because they are all valid responses in case of a dot. You'll need to include them in the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an interview question (as I faced this question on one of my past interview). There are some other approaches with different tradeoff, but anything beyond prefix tree (Trie) will be over-engineering for an interview problem. Just build a trie with all the given words and search on the trie for any query words. At any point, when encountered a dot, search for all possible child nodes from that node and continue searching further by matching the later characters. That's it.